# How to find conflicts in FullCalendar with rrule plugin?

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, rrule, recurring-events

I am using the FullCalendar Library and I use the rrule plugin the show recurring events.
I assume this question can be more generic, but these are the tools that I am using.

When I add a new event, how can I find out, if this will be in conflict with an recurring event?

I am asking as for the setup of a recurring event, I have a start end end, or maybe the recurring event goes into infinity. Thus, I don't have an exact date that I can compare. Basically I have the start date only.